# What was the early church fathers view of interfaith marriage?

Tags: early-church, marriage, church-fathers

I am very opposed to interfaith marriage and believe interfaith marriage to be a fundamentally wrong view, but what was the Early Church Fathers view of interfaith marriage - ie a marriage between spouses professing different religions

Comment: The canon law term is "[mixed marriage](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=34917)" (_matrimonium mixtum_).

Comment: One relevant example (4th century AD) was St. Augustine's parents: Monica was Christian, but Patricius was pagan.  [It was an arranged marriage](https://www.encyclopedia.com/women/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/monica-331-387).  It's interesting that Monica's parents were Christians, *but yet* why did her father agree to marry his daughter to a pagan?  What would the parish priest say about it?  Was it culturally acceptable since Christianity just became legal and there were not many potential *Christian* husbands of acceptable socio-economic status?